# Playframework Scala and CouchDB

Tags: scala, playframework, couchdb, playframework-2.0

I intend on writing a small webapp using the Play framework with Scala and CouchDB. Is there any Scala/CouchDB integration library available?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Play framework has its own [Scala branch](http://scala.playframework.org/).

There's a Scala/CouchDB interface on [GitHub](https://github.com/debasishg/scouchdb).

Comment: Also you can think about using Play 2.0 which was rewritten to scala completely so the integration is even better now. http://www.playframework.org/2.0

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use Play's asynchronous API, where your controller methods have to return futures, you might want to have a look at [my asynchronous library](https://github.com/KimStebel/sprouch).